# How to page a cursor in official mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongo-go

Inspecting the interface Cursor in mongo-go-driver:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/mongo/cursor.go#L37

There's no `Limit` or `Skip` functions.

How can I page the results?

I think I will face the same problem when trying to `Sort` or `Count`.

Is there a way? or, is this simply not yet implemented in the official driver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the find options you can check in package `options`
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/tree/master/mongo/options

```
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), "mongodb://localhost:27017", nil)
// check err
db := client.Database("examples")

coll := db.Collection("inventory")
{
    cursor, err := coll.Find(
        context.Background(),
        options.SetSort(bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.Int64("x", 1))),
        options.SetLimit(30),
        options.SetSkip(5),
    )

    // cursor decode...

}
```

Count with filter

```
count, err :=coll.Count(context.Background(),bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("foo", "bar")))
```

Count from document metadata

```
count, err := coll.EstimatedDocumentCount(context.Background(),countopt.MaxTimeMs(100))
```

**Edit:**

Mongo-go-driver stable v1.0.0 released where they separated the BSON library, Please refar to official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/go/)

Comment: Thanks @M Ashraf ul A there's no examples of those methods in the official documentation! But I should have pick a little more in the source code. Maybe I could have find those functions. Thanks again.

Comment: can you please provide a link to the package? Thanks!

Comment: @rrw in latest beta release package `findopt` become `options` https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/mongo/options/findoptions.go

Comment: no longer works, it shows: type *mongo.Collection has no field or method Count. renamed to CountDocuments